# Adding Google Analytics to an iOS app causes error

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I've added **GAI framework**.

Files :

`- GAI.h
- GAIDictionaryBuilder.h
- GAIFields.h GAILogger.h
- GAITrackedViewController.h
- GAITracker.h
- libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a`

But when I'm trying to build the project, it shows such error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_llvm_gcda_emit_arcs", referenced from:
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAI.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIBatchingDispatcher.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDefaultLogger.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIStringUtil.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
      ...

"_llvm_gcda_emit_function", referenced from:
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in ...

"_llvm_gcda_end_file", referenced from:
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in ...

"_llvm_gcda_increment_indirect_counter", referenced from:
      -[GAI defaultTracker] in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAI.o)
      -[GAI setDefaultTracker:] in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAI.o)
      ...

"_llvm_gcda_start_file", referenced from:
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in ...
```

*ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*

What caused this error?

Update :

```
// AppDelegate.h

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<GAITracker> tracker;

// AppDelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{


[GAI sharedInstance].optOut = YES;
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 120;
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithName: kTrackerName
                                          trackingId: kTrackingId];

//other code 

return YES;
}
```

Comment: copy the code... not only the error..

Comment: Did you include the libraries and frameworks that are required?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18872196/109306 is the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add these classes:

[image]

If you add these, it will work fine.

And I think the best is if you set:

```
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 0;
```

Comment: Where did you find "libGoogleAnalytics.a" and how did you include it in XCode? I only have "libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a" and "libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a" in my Google Analytics zip archive and when I include them in Xcode they get the blank-white-icon that means "I don't know what these files are" from Xcode.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/resources : GoogleAnalyticsiOS_2.0beta4.zip

Comment: Ok, I'm using v3 but I found the solution to my problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The `libGoogleAnalytics.a` file is in the top level of the zip for v3.10.1. It's is a couple folders above the one with the those header files and the `libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a`.

Comment: Mmm ... no libGoogleAnalytics.a in the zip file of the current version (V 3.02), just the ``libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a`` library, which gives the above errors. When I include the ``libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a`` library (which is well part of the zip), it works ... I think they built the wrong library for the latest release ...

Answer (score 11):

I Had the same error : Just add "libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a" into your files like this :

[image: libGoogleAnalyticsServicesXcode5]

I hope this can help you. It's work for me ;)

++

Comment: That's the answer that helped me with v3. Because my project didn't build with exactly the same error message as described in the question when having important all the files you describe here PLUS libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a Your screenshot hinted that I should just remove it :)

Comment: My problem was that I didn't  delete libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a from project.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to all the libraries and frameworks specified in the README file, turns out that you need to include the **AdSupport.framework** and **libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a** (instead of the libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a) to get rid of the build errors while compiling for simulator.

Comment: I searched all day for an answer and this was it for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I got tons of sqlite errors, and the site documentation was poor, but the Readme had it right. List of required frameworks:

```
   CoreData.framework
   Foundation.framework
   SystemConfiguration.framework
   UIKit.framework
   libsqlite3.dylib
   libz.dylib
```

Comment: That's ridiculous they don't mention `libsqlite3.dylib`... I just spent half an hour on that until I saw your answer...

Answer (score 3):

We have just come across this issue and this is slightly out of date so here is an updated answer. The issue we were having after following the instructions on the [Google Analytics website](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/), they instruct you to add the following files `GAI.h`, `GAIDictionaryBuilder.h`, `GAILogger.h`, `GAITrackedViewController.h`, `GAITracker.h` and `libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a` library. What they completely forget to include on the website instructions is the one where you have to include `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a` library. This is included in the zipped download but there is no instructions to indicate to include this in the debug version.

**Note** : In the `readme.txt` `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a` is just referred to as `libGoogleAnalytics.a` Google have failed to update their documentation to include the new name or the correct instructions that indicate this is required in debug.

**Files and Libraries that most be included**

```
GAI.h
GAIDictionaryBuilder.h
GAIFields.h
GAILogger.h
GAITrackedViewController.h
GAITracker.h
libGoogleAnalytics.a // Also know as libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a
libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a
```

Comment: You need to remove libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a

Comment: @MathieuF Why? Please explain don't just give a random comment without explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

I started getting strange errors like this when using **Xcode 5.0** specifically. Even when trying to run an existing project that had been working perfectly previously. Deleting and re-adding the files didn't seem to have any effect.

What I found to be the answer, was to check the search paths under the project build settings. (Build settings tab, then search for 'search paths').

The 'Library search path' values had all had backslashes added to the locations.

Before: `"\$(SRCROOT)/The\ App\ Name/Resources/Libraries/Google\"`

Instead of:

After: `"$(SRCROOT)/The App Name/Resources/Libraries/Google"`

Removing the backslashes fixed any issues and errors I was having.

I'm not sure when or why Xcode was changing these values, but this is what was causing the breaks in my case.

Comment: Try to not use directories names with spaces ... always a big source of trouble ;-).

Comment: Agreed. Still doesn't fix Xcode from adding backslashes at the start and end though: "\$(SRCROOT)" and /Google\"

Comment: I can confirm that, it happen to me too, anyone found a possible explanation?

Answer (score 1):

I have just changed the Google Analytics debug lib (libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a) for the libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a and worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Please First Open `CuteAnimal` Example in GA example folder and if you expand Google Analytics Library you will see these files:

```
GAI.h
GAIDictionaryBuilder.h
GAIFields.h
GAILogger.h
GAITrackedViewController.h
GAITracker.h
libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a
```